# Looking to encrypt data in a database per user

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, database

We're currently using a MySQL database for our (PHP-)system. Every user has a fairly self-contained data-set (a small amount of relationships to other users). We're looking at options to start encrypting the data.

Disk-level encryption is not really an option, because we actually don't want to be able to access the data ourselves. The user's password should (indirectly) be the key to the data.

In MySQL that leaves field-level encryption, which is not optimal in terms of performance. Indexing and schema changes would be hard.

I'm open to using a new dbms system, relational or not. (as long as it's open source) I'm hoping for some information, or suggestions on what a good way would be to proceed with.

**Edit:**

I don't think this is a fair closure. If there were multiple tools to consider, I'd understand it.. but at the moment I just don't really know where to begin. No tool I'm aware of has native support for what I'm looking for.

I know it's tempting to just hit that close button for anything that remotely resembles 'Off-topic' or any other reasons, but instead of just liberally hitting it, let me know how I can actually improve this question.